# How to draw a binary linear equation in R?

Tags: r, plot, 3d, binary

Now I have a binary linear equation **z = wx1 - (1-w)x2**, and **w** varys from 0 to 1 in 0.1 intervals. With two variables x1 and x2, I want to plot this equation with R.

With constraints `x1<=19266669.5`, and `x2<=52575341.065`

I tried the code below, but it didn't work.

```
w=seq(0,1,0.1)
x1<=19266669.5
x2<=52575341.065
z = w*x1 - (1-w)*x2
plot(w,z,type="l",lwd=2,col="red",main="z = w*x1 - (1-w)*x2")
```

How should I improve the code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you want `x1` and `x2` to be equal to (or be assigned the values of) 19266669.5 and 52575341.065, respectively, you need to use the `<-` operator, not `<=`. When I change this, the plot works.

Comment: Thank you! I mean x1 is less than or equal to 19266669.5

Comment: In that case these two lines are unnecessary since they do not affect the values of x1, x2 or z. The logical statements will return values of TRUE or FALSE, but you do not assign those values to an object so they are never used for anything. You should provide a sample of x1 and x2 and explain what did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your are assigning values so, it is an assignment error, you should use first (based on your snippet) the operator **<-**
Then to plot use <=, or whatever relational operator you want.

Assignments operators:

```
x <- value
x <<- value<="" code="">
value -> x
value ->> x
x = value
```